# How to make a progress bar in widgets(home screen) in android/ios using react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, widget, progress-bar

Seeking guidance on adding progress bar widgets to the home screen in React Native for Android and iOS. I'm aware of customization through native code, but I'm specifically looking for solutions within React Native. Any insights, recommended libraries, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. I want to ensure a smooth implementation without delving into extensive native modifications. Thanks!

Comment: I'd use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress.